# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{3}\sqrt{4+7x}\;dx $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I'm still trying to understand how to solve these kind of problems like:

$$\int_{0}^{3}\sqrt{4+7x}\;dx $$

I already let $u = 4+7x$. Where do I go from here to evaluate the definite integral?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Next step is to calculate $du$ then calculate limits for the integral after the substitution

Comment: Not that there's anything wrong with this question, necessarily, but what's up with the upvotes?

Answer (score 5):

> $$\int_{0}^{3}\sqrt{4+7x} ~dx $$

You let $u = 4+7x$, so $du=7dx,~dx=\frac{1}7du$. The lower limit $x=0$ in converted to $u=4$, and upper limit $x=3$ is converted to $u=25$, so the integral becomes:

$$\int_{4}^{25}\sqrt{u} ~\frac{1}7du=\frac{1}7\cdot\frac{2}3u^{3/2}|_4^{25}=\frac{2}{21}(125-8)=\frac{78}7$$

Answer (score 1):

You can directly guess the antiderivative $$\int \sqrt{4+7x}\,dx = c\,(4+7x)^{3/2}$$ and then by differentiating determine that $$c= {1\over 7}\cdot {2\over 3}$$ Finally calculate the increment from $x=0$ to $x=3.$